# Removing the zero level of an imagemap using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the `geom_tile` to draw an imagemap and want to clear out the zero level for clarity.

```
#dummy data
set.seed(1)
tdata <- data.frame(cat1=rep(letters[1:3],4),cat2=sort(rep(LETTERS[1:4],3)),val=rpois(12,1.5))
tdata$val<-tdata$val/max(tdata$val)
```

I have found 2 ways to do this but both have their drawbacks:

**1)**

```
qplot(cat1,cat2,data=tdata,geom="tile",fill=val) + scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(.Machine$double.eps,1))
```

This has the drawback that the min value colour isn't printed in the scale.

**2)**

```
qplot(cat1,cat2,data=tdata,geom="tile",fill=val,alpha=ifelse(val,1,0))
```

This has the drawback that the alpha scale is plotted too. Wrapping the alpha argument in an `I()` causes it to fail.

Is there a way to do this without the drawbacks?

Comment: What do you mean by 'clear out the zero level'? For one thing, your test data doesnt have any zeroes in tdata$val...

Comment: It should do, unless `set.seed(1)` generates different random numbers on your system. I mean to not plot anything if the value is zero, rather than the bottom end of the colour ramp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset your data.

```
qplot(..., data=subset(tdata, val > 0), ...) 
qplot(cat1,cat2,data=subset(tdata, val >0),geom="tile",fill=val)
```